# I am getting an Error when trying to load a map bigger than 4

Tags: java, dictionary

The Error:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
    at stockman.mapping.Map.loadMap(Map.java:67)
    at stockman.mapping.Map.<init>(Map.java:23)
    at stockman.gamestate.Level1State.init(Level1State.java:21)
    at stockman.gamestate.GameState.<init>(GameState.java:18)
    at stockman.gamestate.Level1State.<init>(Level1State.java:15)
    at stockman.gamestate.MenuState.keyPressed(MenuState.java:83)
    at stockman.gamestate.GameStateManager.keyPressed(GameStateManager.java:25)
    at stockman.main.GamePanel.keyPressed(GamePanel.java:95)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.keyPressed(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.preDispatchKeyEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

My Map Code:

```
public class Map {

    private String path;
    private int height, width;

    private Block[][] blocks;

    public Map(String loadPath)
    {

        path = loadPath;

        loadMap();

    }


    public void draw(Graphics g){

        for(int i = 0; i < blocks.length; i++){

            for(int j = 0; j < blocks[0].length; j++){

                blocks[j][i].draw(g);

            }
        }

    }

    public Block[][] getBlocks(){

        return blocks;

    }

    public void loadMap(){

        InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream(path);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try{

            width = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
            height = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

            blocks = new Block[height][width];

            for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){

            String line = br.readLine();

            String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

                for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){

                    blocks[x][y]= new Block(x * Block.blockSize ,y * Block.blockSize, Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]));

                }

            }


        }catch(NumberFormatException | IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

My map1.map code:

```
4
4
1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1 
1 1 1 1
```

I cant get the map to go any bigger than 4, when I try I get the map any bigger I get that error

This is my block Class:

public class Block extends Rectangle {

```
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public static final int blockSize = 64;
private int id;

public Block(int x, int y, int id) {
    setBounds(x, y, blockSize, blockSize);
    this.id = id;
}

public void tick() {

}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);

    if(id != 0){

    g.fillRect(x - (int)GameState.xOffset, y - (int)GameState.yOffset, width, height);
    }
}

//getters and setters

public void setID(int id){

    this.id = id;

}

public int getID(){

    return id;
}

}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could help me, I'm quite good at programming but this one has got me completely stumped!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     blocks = new Block[height][width];

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++){

    String line = br.readLine();

    String[] tokens = line.split("\\s+");

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++){

            blocks[x][y]= new Block(x * Block.blockSize ,y * Block.blockSize, Integer.parseInt(tokens[x]));

        }

    }
```

See how you're setting up the array with blocks[height][width] and then assigning them blocks[x][y] (where x is predictably looping until width and y height) which is the other way around. That's why you're blowing the array index.

Your draw function also looks like it is suspect, for the same reasons.

Comment: I changed x to width and y to height and no luck

Comment: Can you show me the map that it blows up on please? You say it works at 4

Comment: I did it a different way, by setting the height and width in the code instead of the map. Thanks for your help though!